# How pass a parameter to a from:toObject:selector:?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, three20, ttnavigator

I have a TableView with several rows. When a row is selected, I need to perform a selector. I do something like this:

```
 [TTTableTextItem 
  itemWithText:NSLocalizedString(@"Cash","Title:Cash")
  URL:[NSString @"tt://payment/add/%d",5]
  accessoryURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:detail,5]],
```

and declare:

```
 ..................... 
 TTURLMap* map = [TTNavigator navigator].URLMap;
 [map from:@"tt://payment/add/(source:)" toObject:self selector:@selector(addPayment:)];
 ..................... 

- (void) addPayment:(PaymentType)theType {
   ALog(@"%ld",theType);
}
```

But, theType always get 0. So, how I can pass the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (I think) is to do this:

```
[map from:@"tt://payment/add/(addPayment:)" toObject:self];
```

The `addPayment:` in parentheses implies what selector of `self` to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

What is your datasource? Table Views do not store their own data. Have you used the correct protocal?

Comment: This have nothing to do with datasource. The issues is that I need to pass a parameter to a URL of type from:toObject:selector:.